# Unable to show UIactivityViewController on tableview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am unable to show **UIactivityViewController** inside custom tableview.I have a button inside table cell.On click of that button i am showing the **UIActonSheet**.On click of **UIActionSheet** delegate i am showing the **UIActivityController**.When i set source view as main view then it works but when i set source view as tableview then it does not work properly.

Below is the code.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (actionSheet.tag == 100)
    {
       if(buttonIndex==0)
       {
           [self deletePost];
       }
       else if(buttonIndex==1)
       {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            EditPostController *vc = (EditPostController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditPostController"];
            HomeCell *cell=(HomeCell *)[self.table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:unv_indexPath];
           if (cell.beizer_image.image!=nil) {
               vc.postImage=cell.beizer_image.image;
           }
           vc.editPost=[arr_post objectAtIndex:unv_index];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
       }
      else if(buttonIndex==2)
      {
          HomeCell *cell=(HomeCell *)[self.table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:unv_indexPath];
          NSArray *postItems;UIImage *screeshotTaken;
          Post *pst=[arr_post objectAtIndex:unv_index];
          if (cell.beizer_image.image!=nil) {
              screeshotTaken=cell.beizer_image.image;
          }
          if (screeshotTaken==nil) {
             postItems = @[pst.post_title,cell.tv_post.text];
          }
          else
          {
              postItems = @[pst.post_title,cell.tv_post.text,screeshotTaken];

          }
          UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:postItems applicationActivities:nil];
          if(IS_IPHONE)
          {
              [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
          }
          else
          {
              controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
              controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(cell.btn_more.frame.origin.x+20,100 ,0, 0);
              [self presentViewController:controller
                                 animated:YES
                               completion:nil];
          }
      }
    }
    else if (actionSheet.tag == 200)
    {

        if (buttonIndex==0) {

            [self reportPostSelection];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Action sheet is deprecated in ios 8.3 and above version.

Comment: First of all action sheet is deprecated in iOS 9

Comment: Who cares man.I want to still use it